# how to copy the name of the folders

Tags: python, if-statement, copy, directory, names

I am new to python and I am really trying to accomplish a simple task. I am trying to copy only the names of some folders to another folder (ex: folderA). I do not care about the contents of those folders, I do care to copy only their names.

(the folder names I want to copy are under batch_2016: sin_1008100, sin_1010987, sin_10109)
below is what I have written but is not working as I expect

```
batch_path = '/net/storage/batch_2016' # where the folders are located
batch_name = raw_input("batch name: ") # im giving a new folder name
os.chdir(batch_path)
print(os.getcwd())

for fName in os.listdir('.'):
    if fName.startswith("sin"):
        os.makedirs(batch_name)
        os.chdir(batch_name)
        os.makedirs(fName)
```

I am not getting any error to post but when it is running it creates 3 batch_name folders and each folder has the folder_names I want to copy.
So if the new folder name is FolderA, it has inside

```
FolderA, sin_1008100
FolderA, sin_1010987
FolderA, sin_10109
```

I guess this is because of the loop but I am not sure how to fix that.
Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
import os

batch_path = '/net/storage/batch_2016' # where the folders are located
batch_name = raw_input("batch name: ") # im giving a new folder name
os.chdir(batch_path)
print(os.getcwd())

os.makedirs(batch_name)

for fName in os.listdir('.'):
    if fName.startswith("sin"):
        os.makedirs(batch_name + "/" + fName)
        # alternatively, os.makedirs("../" + batch_name + "/" + fName)
```

Comment: Yes, it works! that is what i was looking for, thank you. by the way, what is the "/" for?

Comment: The "/" is part of the path - you'll create a file called fName inside the directory batch_name. For example, with batch_name="/net/storage/greatbatch" and fName="sin_42", you get /net/storage/greatbatch/sin_42.